# Why doesnt 'Instantiate' not exist according to Unit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, instantiation, gameobject

I'm encountering an issue in my Unity script where the `Instantiate` method is not being recognized. I'm trying to instantiate a projectile in a ranged attack state, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Assets\Scripts\RobotBehaviour\States\RobotAttackStateRanged.cs(48,33): error CS0103: The name 'Instantiate' does not exist in the current context
```

I've ensured that the `UnityEngine` namespace is imported at the top of my script, and the Unity version I'm using should support the `Instantiate` method. Despite these checks, the error persists.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

`// Inside AttackPlayerRanged method GameObject projectile = Instantiate(enemyProjectile, RangedAttackSpawnPoint.position, RangedAttackSpawnPoint.rotation);`

Here is the entire script this code is a part of, if it will be useful:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class RobotAttackStateRanged : RobotBaseState
{
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public bool readyToShoot;
    public Transform playerTransform;
    public Transform robottransform;
    public float throwCooldown = 5f;
    public GameObject enemyProjectile;
    public Transform RangedAttackSpawnPoint;
    public float projectileForce;

    public override void EnterState(RobotStateManager robot)
    {
        Assign(robot);
        Debug.Log("Attack State Mode: Ranged Activated!");
    }

    public override void UpdateState(RobotStateManager robot)
    {
        // Other update logic if needed
    }

    public override void FixedUpdateState(RobotStateManager robot)
    {
        AttackPlayerRanged(robot);
    }

    public override void OnCollisionEnter(RobotStateManager robot)
    {
        // Handle collision logic if needed
    }

    public override void Assign(RobotStateManager robot)
    {
        agent = robot.agent;
        playerTransform = robot.playerTransform;
        robottransform = robot.robottransform;
        enemyProjectile = robot.enemyProjectile;
        RangedAttackSpawnPoint = robot.RangedAttackSpawnPoint;
        projectileForce = robot.projectileForce;
    }

    private void AttackPlayerRanged(RobotStateManager robot)
    {
        readyToShoot = false;

        if (enemyProjectile != null && RangedAttackSpawnPoint != null)
        {
            // Getting direction from the enemy to the player
            Vector3 directionToPlayer = (playerTransform.position - robottransform.position).normalized;

            // LookAt makes the enemy face the player
            agent.transform.LookAt(playerTransform);

            // Instantiating projectile to be fired at the player
            GameObject projectile = Instantiate(enemyProjectile, RangedAttackSpawnPoint.position, RangedAttackSpawnPoint.rotation);

            // Acquiring rigidbody component so that the object can be fired using Unity physics engine
            Rigidbody projectileRb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

            if (projectileRb != null)
            {
                // DirectionToPlayer used to determine the force direction
                projectileRb.AddForce(directionToPlayer * projectileForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Rigidbody component not found on the projectile.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Enemy projectile or spawn point not assigned.");
        }

        robot.Invoke(nameof(ResetEnemyShoot), throwCooldown);
    }

    private void ResetEnemyShoot()
    {
        readyToShoot = true;
    }
}
```

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to instantiate an object so that I can then fire it at the enemy, but before I can even run the program I'm told that instantiate doesn't exist. For the record I'm using Unity 2022.3.1f1, which I believe is quite a recent version, so I'm not sure why else it isn't being detected.

Comment: I suspect that `RobotBaseState` is not a `MonoBehaviour`. In such a case you should use `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate` (or `GameObject.Instantiate`) instead of `Instantiate`

Comment: @Morion always `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate` .. it is implemented there. `GameObject` just inherits from `UnityEngine.Object` that's why in theory it would work as well but you should always prefer the base in such case ;)

Comment: @derHugo this is not in theory, it will definitely work) and yes, any code analyzer will suggest a fix with "use base class". however, since it works, I mentioned it =)